# Checksum error with Dell Inspiron 1470

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron that when I turn it on it show the dell logo then goes to a black screen with the text:

```
ERROR 0271:check date and time settings
WARNING
0251:System CMOS checksum bad- Default configuration used
press <F1> to resume, <F2> to setup
```

I have replaced the CMOS battery already and there has been no change.
Any ideas as too how to fix it?

Comment: Have you set it up as intended after replacing the battery?

Comment: Have you tried to press F2 and then reset the BIOS ?

Comment: Get the Dell hardware diagnostics app on bootable USB and test the hardware

Comment: Verify you installed the new battery properly.  You should also set the time and date.  If it resets after any action then the battery you used is potentially not functional.

Comment: I definitely installed the battery properly, how exactly would I Get the Dell hardware diagnostics app on bootable USB and test the hardware? Like where do I find the diagnostics app and how do  I implement it? I apologize for my lack of knowledge, I am still very new at this.